# C# Facebook app / post on site

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-apps

im very new with Facebook apps and read several threads for creating them, but I have some problems with it.
First of all what I want to do: I want to create a web application that is able to post pictures, text and links on a facebook page that is managed by me.

I used the Facebook C# SDK: [here!](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk)

What I have:

```
string facebookPageId = "<my page id>";

string app_id = "<my app id>";
string app_secret = "<my app secret>";
string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

var fb = new FacebookClient();

dynamic res = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
     client_id = app_id,
     client_secret = app_secret,
     grant_type = "client_credentials"
});

var access_token = res.access_token;

dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.access_token = access_token;
messagePost.link = "http://www.test.at";
messagePost.name = "Testbot";
messagePost.caption = "{*actor*} " + "hello this is a test"; 
messagePost.description = "[SOME_DESCRIPTION]";

FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(access_token);
app.AppId = app_id;
app.AppSecret = app_secret;

try
{
     var result = app.Post("/hrechttest" + "/feed", messagePost);
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Well the code runs without any exceptions but in the output window I get the following:

```
Exception thrown: 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' in Facebook.dll
```

The next problem is:
As I understood it you must link your facebook app with your facebook page, but when I want to do that I cant select the page:
[image]

So what I did wrong or missed?

Comment: try again by reset the permissions

Answer (score 0):

`publish_stream` is deprecated since many years, `publish_pages` is the correct permission to post to a Page (as Page).

API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish

Make sure you are using a Page Token, not a User Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

How to create Page Apps is explained in the docs too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Comment: I did the changes you suggested but now I´m getting this error: "Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: make sure your access token is a PAGE token, and make sure it includes the publish_pages permission. the error message is very clear.

Comment: yes I understand that, but the access token comes from the first facebook client call. So you mean this access token I get is a user access token and no page access token?

Comment: read my answer and check out the links i posted and you will understand the difference and how to generate page tokens. in your code, i do not see anything about a page token.

Comment: Now I got it: I had to list all my pages in GraphExplorer with "me/accounts" and then copy and paste the listed access_token. Will this access token expire?

Comment: yes. PLEASE start reading the links in my answer, everything you need to know is in there ;) - i don´t add links to my answer just for fun, they are all important.